# doxygen using absolute file path instead of symlinked(original) path

Tags: doxygen, symlink

When doxygen is generating a File List it will be using the absolute path of the included files instead of the symlinked (original) path and the generated output file list is a bit ugly because of the absolute path of the files.

I have tried to use FULL_PATH_NAMES and STRIP_FROM_PATH but I would need something like REPLACE_PATH_NAMES

I have a project with following structure:

```
/home/user/workspace/myproject
 - src
 - inc
 - usercode
   - src
   - inc
 - mylibs
   - my_awsome_external_lib1 --> /home/user/workspace/somecoollib
   - my_awsome_external_lib2 --> /home/user/workspace/wherever/lib2
   - my_awsome_external_lib3 --> /home/user/wherever3/lib3
```

So for example a file in one of the libs:

```
/home/user/workspace/myproject/mylibs/my_awsome_external_lib1/src/source.c --> /home/user/workspace/somecoollib/src/source.c
```

Will be included as

```
somecoollib/src/source.c
```

instead of

```
my_awsome_external_lib1/src/source.c
```

I don't really want to refactor my directory structure or use hard links.
Anyone has any idea how can I solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: doxygen converts the filenames to an absolute filename and forgetting the original name. What you would like to have is (in my words!) a not existing option: `USE_ORIGINAL_NAME=YES`. Maybe best to issue an, enhancement, issue in the doxygen issue tracker on github.

Comment: Yeah, thanks that would be a neat solution. I thought  might have missed something in the documentation, but cant see any kind of hacky way either to change the file path.

Comment: doxygen issue: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7401